# How use Bootstrap-carousel lazy Multiple image SLide loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The Slider Contain div are slowly show when i am left and right Button is click
How use  ***.slidder-imgClass*** is ***SLowly Show fade and move*** 
How use Jquery and Java Script...........

## [I wanted This Style](http://www.hulu.com/)

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic">
      <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel-example-captions">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
                  <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item ">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
          </div>
           <div class="item ">
                <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
               <div class="slider-img">
                    <img src="http://img.tjskl.org.cn/pic/z2577d9d-200x200-1/pinarello_lungavita_2010_single_speed_bike.jpg" alt="item" />
                </div>
          </div>

         </div>
         <a data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="left carousel-control">left</a> 
          <a data-slide="next" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="right carousel-control">right </a>  

        </div>
```

jquery

```
  $("a.left").click(function(){
      // how use slider-img are slow show and hide
   });
  $("a.right").click(function(){
      // how use slider-img are slow show and hide
  });
```

## [SEEDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/3E84N/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one will work for you:

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3E84N/5/)

```
.carousel.c-fade .active.left,
 .carousel.c-fade .active.right {
     left: 0;
     z-index: 2;
     opacity: 0;
     filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   }
   .carousel.c-fade .next,
   .carousel.c-fade .prev {
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
   }
   .carousel.c-fade .carousel-control {
      z-index: 3;

    }
```

Comment: thank sir, but i wanted this example http://www.hulu.com/, it is beautiful show image and slide.. how use jquery

Comment: You have to write some `CSS` style to match with `hulu.com` slider. :)

Comment: @itendra Yadav, your answer is good, but i not allright. i wanted this style http://www.hulu.com/. how use sir?..